# Receive error regarding licensing

Tags: error

I get this, instead of the admin page, please advise.

// http://civicrm.org/licensing //

Comment: Can you please explain your question in more detail? Under what circumstances do you see it? How did you install Civi? What CMS are you using? Was it working before? What happened right before it stopped working?

Comment: I updated CiviCRM on my website. I can get to Admin Utilities and the Settings page, but when I click on any Civi links from the Civi settings page, it goes to a blank white page with the error message I posted above. It's as if the program was requesting a license validation or something. I do not know how to get to the actual admin page.

Comment: I am using update Wordpress on PHP 8.0. I admit that I may have updated clumsily. But I do not want to reinstall from scratch because I have so much in the database.

Answer (score 2):

CiviCRM doesn't require any license validation to run, the text you are seeing is just a standard part of the normal page footer. You are just noticing it now because the rest of the page appears to be broken.

Based on your comment, "clumsy upgrade" might be the issue. To fix this you do not need to delete anything from your database or lose any data. Simply delete the civicrm code and replace it with a fresh copy. Your data will not be lost, as replacing the code is standard upgrade procedure.

Refer to the [CiviCRM on Wordpress Upgrade Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/) for more details. Don't forget to do the database upgrade step at the end.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Truly appreciated. I will do as you suggest and hope it all works. GREAT program, very useful.